# Is there a Perl module for parsing columnar text?

Tags: perl, parsing, module

Let's say I have a tab-delimited text file that contains data arranged in columns (with headers).

It is possible that different columns may be "stacked" into a "worksheet"-like arrangement, i.e. there is some divider (that may or may not be known ahead of time) that allows different columns to be arranged vertically.

Is there a Perl module that facilitates parsing of columnar data in this text file into a data structure (e.g., a hash table with the key being the column header, and the value being an array of column data scalars)?

**EDIT** By "stacked", I mean that a column of text may include multiple, individual "vectors" of data, each with different headers and different lengths. Admittedly, this complicates parsing.

**EDIT** I'm honestly not sure where the confusion is. Nonetheless, here's an example:

```
header_one\theader_three
data_1\tdata_7
data_2\tdata_8
data_3\tdata_9
\tdata_10
header_two\tdata_11
data_4\theader_four
data_5\tdata_12
data_6\tdata_13
\tdata_14
```

The script would turn this into a hash table with four keys: `header_one`, `header_two`, `header_three`, and `header_four`, each key referencing an array reference pointing to the `data_n` elements underneath the header.

Comment: You'd have to probably show an example... I'm having a hard time visualising.

Comment: I don't think I have an example I can readily paste and format on this page. Just imagine one column of data (with a unique header) and another immediately below it (with a different, unique header).

Comment: SHOW AN EXAMPLE! If you want anybody to come up with something that will work.

Comment: Just make up an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is close to what you are talking about.  If the number of columns changes then the input is treated as if it were a different table.  This code could be easily modified to recognize some other marker (such as a line of equal signs) instead of using the column counts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

#setup the parser, here we want tab separated and we allow
#loose quoting, so qq/foo\t"bar\tbaz"\tquux/ is 
#("foo", "bar\tbaz", "quux")
my $p = Text::CSV_XS->new(
    {
        sep_char           => "\t",
        allow_loose_quotes => 1,
    }
);

my @stacked;
my $cur = 0;
while (<>) {
    $p->parse($_) or die $p->error_input;
    my @rec = $p->fields;
    #normal case, just add the record to the last
    #section in @stacked
    if (@rec == $cur) {
        push @{$stacked[-1]}, \@rec;
        next;
    }
    #if the number of columns don't match then
    #we have a new section
    push @stacked, [\@rec];
    $cur = @rec; #set the new number of columns
}

for my $table (@stacked) {
    print "header: ", join("::", @{$table->[0]}), "\n";
    for my $i (1 .. $#$table) {
        print "data: ", join("::", @{$table->[$i]}), "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~jzucker/DBD-CSV-0.22/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) if possible, though your "stacked" requirement (which I don't fully understand) probably would require some manual parsing, using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.64/CSV_XS.pm).

Don't be fooled by their names - they can parse with any separators, not just commas.

Answer (score -1):

Not very smooth, but I've been doing it like this:

```
        my $recordType = unpack("A3", $_);

        if ($recordType eq "APT")
        {
            $currentKey = parseFAAAirportAirportRecord($_);
        }
        elsif ($recordType eq "ATT")
        {
            parseFAAAirportAttendenceRecord($currentKey, $_);
        }
        elsif ($recordType eq "RWY")
        {
            parseFAAAirportRunwayRecord($currentKey, $_);
        }
        elsif ($recordType eq "RMK")
        {
            parseFAAAirportRemarkRecord($currentKey, $_);
        }
...
sub parseFAAAirportAirportRecord($)
{
    my ($line) = @_;

    my ($recordType, $datasource_key, $type, $id, $effDate, $faaRegion,
        $faaFieldOffice, $state, $stateName, $county, $countyState,
        $city, $name, $ownershipType, $facilityUse, $ownersName,
        $ownersAddress, $ownersCityStateZip, $ownersPhone, $facilitiesManager,
        $managersAddress, $managersCityStateZip, $managersPhone,
        $formattedLat, $secondsLat, $formattedLong, $secondsLong,
        $refDetermined, $elev, $elevDetermined, $magVar, $magVarEpoch, $tph,
        $sectional, $distFromTown, $dirFromTown, $acres,
        $bndryARTCC, $bndryARTCCid,
        $bndryARTCCname, $respARTCC, $respARTCCid, $respARTCCname,
        $fssOnAirport, $fssId, $fssName, $fssPhone, $fssTollFreePhone,
        $altFss, $altFssName,
        $altFssPhone, $notamFacility, $notamD, $arptActDate,
        $arptStatusCode, $arptCert,
        $naspAgreementCode, $arptAirspcAnalysed, $aoe, $custLandRights,
        $militaryJoint, $militaryRights, $nationalEmergency, $milUse,
        $inspMeth, $inspAgency, $lastInsp, $lastInfo, $fuel, $airframeRepairs
,
        $engineRepairs, $bottledOyxgen, $bulkOxygen,
        $lightingSchedule, $tower, $unicomFreqs, $ctafFreq, $segmentedCircle,
        $lens, $landingFee, $isMedical,
        $numBasedSEL, $numBasedMEL, $numBasedJet,
        $numBasedHelo, $numBasedGliders, $numBasedMilitary,
        $numBasedUltraLight,
        $numScheduledOperation, $numCommuter, $numAirTaxi,
        $numGAlocal, $numGAItinerant,
        $numMil, $countEndingDate,
        $aptPosSrc, $aptPosSrcDate, $aptElevSrc, $aptElevSrcDate,
        $contractFuel, $transientStorage, $otherServices, $windIndicator,
        $icaoId) =
        unpack("A3 A11 A13 A4 A10 A3 A4 A2 A20 A21 A2 A40 " .
        "A42 A2 A2 A35 A72 A45 A16 A35 A72 A45 A16 A15 A12 A15 A12 A1 A5 A1 " .
        "A3 A4 A4 A30 A2 A3 A5 A4 A3 A30 A4 A3 A30 A1 A4 A30 A16 A16 " .
        "A4 A30 A16 A4 " .
        "A1 A7 A2 A15 A7 A13 A1 A1 A1 A1 A18 A6 A2 A1 A8 A8 A40 A5 A5 A8 " .
        "A8 A9 A1 A42 A7 A4 A3 A1 A1 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 " .
        "A6 A6 A6 A6 A6 A6 A10" .
        "A16 A10 A16 A10 A1 A12 A71 A3 A7", $line);
```